# How to derive coordinates of the vertices in the unit-distance embedding of the Golomb Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

With recent [interest](https://polymathprojects.org/2018/04/10/polymath-proposal-finding-simpler-unit-distance-graphs-of-chromatic-number-5/) in the [Hadwiger-Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem) problem on the chromatic number of the plane, thanks to de Grey's [theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02385) that $CNP\ge5$, I've been looking at unit-distance embeddings of various graphs with chromatic number $\chi\ge 4$.

For example, looking at the unit-distance embedding of the [Moser spindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser_spindle), it's clear that three of the vertices form an isosceles triangle with sides $(1,2\sqrt{3},2\sqrt{3})$.

However, looking at the unit-distance embedding of the [Golomb graph](https://euclidlab.org/camp-euclid/2013/summer/group-1/index.php?title=Bounds_on_the_chromatic_number_of_the_plane), I can't see a quick way to deduce the coordinates of the inner triangle.

[image: Golomb Graph, courtesy of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GolombGraph.html]

All of the edges in the graph above are of length $1$.

> Is there a quick "Elements-style" explanation of the coordinates of the vertices in the unit-embedding of Golomb graph?  Is there a straightforward compass-and-straightedge construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by constructing the middle equilateral triangle and the blue point in its center.

Now you can put down the outer green point, because it has a known distance from the blue and inner yellow points.

Finally complete the outer hexagon.

(If you want coordinates in a system where the outer hexagon to have an axis-parallel side, you now need to rotate the entire drawing appropriately).

Comment: Thanks!  I was stuck looking at the outer hexagon axis-parallel.

Comment: @MarkS: You can also draw the hexagon first, find the center of one of its unit triangles, and then draw a circle with the blue point as center. That happens to be the circumcircle of the central triangle, and you can then find its corners by intersecting it with unit circles centered at the outer green/yellow points.